# Wrong routs for view in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I have some code:

routes.php

```
Route::get('/countries/{country1}', [
    'uses' => 'CountryController@editCountr',
    'as' => 'edit1'
    ]);
Route::get('/countries', ['uses' => 'CountryController@getAll', 'as' => 'countries']);
```

CountryController.php

```
public function editCountr($country1){
    $countries = Country::where('country','=', $country1);
    return view('countryedit')->with('country1', $countries);
}
```

countries.blade.php

```
<a href="{{route('edit1')}}">{{$country->country}}</a>
```

So, I have a problem:
My links in countries.blade.php looks like http://localhost:8000/countries/%7Bcountry1%7D

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you must get an object in your conroller:

```
public function editCountr($country1){
    $countries = Country::where('country','=', $country1)->first();
    return view('countryedit')->with('country1', $countries);
}
```

You must provide attribute to route function:

```
   <a href="{{route('edit1', ['country1' => $country1->country])}}">{{$country1->country}}</a>
```